# " 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'load_parent_word2vec_format' " error

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, word2vec

I am trying to run an old code which uses python 2.7, and since it runs on the slow version of Word2Vec I want to update it to Python3 and when I did so I got this error:

'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'load_parent_word2vec_format', with updated libraries.

This it the commad that makes the error:

```
self.model.load_parent_word2vec_format(fname=tmp_fname)
```

I am trying to find a way to manage this in python3 and be able to run the code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which libraries you're using or show the full 'traceback' error you're getting, so it's not certain what code is involved in your error.

`load_parent_word2vec_format()` is not a word2vec-related method I recognize, though it is similarly-named to the Gensim library metho `load_word2vec_format()`. The only potential match findable by Google is a customized `Word2Vec` implementation in this Github project: https://github.com/mims-harvard/ohmnet/tree/master/ohmnet/gensimmod/model

If that's the variant `Word2Vec` you need to use, you'd have to have that project installed & working in Python 3 – which might be a challenge if the original authors of that project haven't attempted it, or updated the code in 7 years. (From a quick glance at that project, it doesn't look like its special alternative functionality was, even then, implemented via the 'fast' optimized Cython code-paths. So even getting it working wouldn't deliver `OhmNet` operations at high speed without additional work the original authors didn't seem to do.)

If you just need plain `Word2Vec`, as if imported from an unaltered `gensim` package (which works fine in Python 3.x), then you can load plain word2vec word-vector sets using the standard `load_word2vec_format()` method.